# Showing the input when using redirection operators in command prompt

Tags: redirect, input, command, prompt

Hopefully this is an easy/dumb question.

I am redirecting program input and output to text files in Windows.

Example:

```
program.exe < in.txt > out.txt
```

But the text that is inputted from the input file isn't shown in the output file (or screen when not redirecting the output). Is there any way to show it easily? I've tried google but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what `program.exe` is doing with the input.  You will only see it in the file (or the console if you dont redirect) if `program.exe` actually writes its output to standard out.  If you need to send the input multiple ways (such as to the program and also the screen at the same time) and the program itself doesnt actually make provision for this, you need something like `tee` - or a real shell like `bash`.

Comment: The program is made to interact with a user, so all input is done (by default) from the keyboard and all output is onto the screen, not to a file. The output file only shows what the program prints, not what is inputted to it. I can easily just type it and copy the command prompt results, but it seems like this should be an easy way to do this in windows and it's just bugging me.

Comment: Unless the program actually echo's back what the user has entered via the keyboard, there is no way for it to ever end up on standard out and thus into your file if you redirect standard out.